# Create a model for existing controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Check MVC code bellow. I have created this controller but i want to add a Model with this controller to Retrieve user email list and id. But problem is all online tutorial says create model during create controller since i already created controller i have to create model manually now. Please advice me any solution how can i Create model for this controller? Please also note i have to access that Model from "SubmitAction" method on this controller

```
    namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
    {
        [AdministratorOnlyPermission]
        public class EmailCampaignController : Controller
        {

            // GET: Email Campaign
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public static IRestResponse SendSimpleMessage()
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient();
                client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
                client.Authenticator =
                    new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                                "key-34d6fd732e9ba43a2fakeeeeeee4b60c");
                RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
                request.AddParameter("domain", "sandboxc8436ac0db054b45986303cb8fd3944a.mailgun.org", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
                request.AddParameter("from", "Excited User <mailgun@sandboxc8436ac0db054b45986303cb8fd3944a.mailgun.org>");
                request.AddParameter("to", "lia@gmail.com");
                request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
                request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
                request.Method = Method.POST;
                return client.Execute(request);
            }



            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection collection)
            {
                //var userType = Request["userType"];
                //var emailContent = Request["emailContent"];
                //SendSimpleMessage();
                //ViewBag.Message = "Hello " + Request["userType"];

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your form is submitting to the controller, your model will vary.

Let's say you were using `FormCollection` as the parameter in your `SubmitAction` like below:

```
public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection collection)
```

And let's further say your form had controls with the following names and you were getting these items from the `FormCollection`:

1. Name
2. Age

Now you want to use a model instead. All you have to do is to create a class that has those properties and call the class whatever you like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The MVC DefaultBinder will take the items you are submitting in your form, take the `name` of the form controls and look for those in your `Person` class, if it finds a property with a matching name, it will set that property of the `Person` class. It will do that for all the controls in the form.

You will change the signature of the action to accept the model as parameter like this:

```
public ActionResult SubmitAction(Person person)
```

Comment: But "Name" and "Age" are column names. How entityframework will select the table name? is the "person" is table name? or what?

Comment: @TeenaR Like I said, you can call the class whatever you want. Plus you never mentioned about EF. You will take the thing coming into the action, such as `Person`, and then from that create the thing you want to add to the database.

Comment: sorry mightbe bad question. if i don't say on which table operation should be happen then how system will know that? i'm confused here. suppose: i have two different table contains same column called "Age" then system will confused about table isn't it?

Comment: You are confusing models (in MVC) with and `Entity Model`. Let's continue with my example of `Person`. That is a model (not an entity model). You can take that and create your entity model from that and your entity model can be called `Customer` or anything. You can also use your entity model in your action if you want. Some people call the mvc model (view model).